# How do I convert a couple of Google Sheets columns into a JSON string?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm working on a piece of code that will convert two columns (A, B) into key/value pairs  with JSON formatting. I can't figure out how to make it work. I currently have a function that will read the top row (keys) and the bottom row of the values, but I can't get it to show the rows in between. I'm not an engineer or a developer, but I do enjoy coding.

The sheet looks like this:

```
+-------+-------------+
| A     | B           |
+-------+-------------+
| code  | description |
+-------+-------------+
| brand | microsoft   |
+-------+-------------+
| size  | large       |
+-------+-------------+
| color | green       |
+-------+-------------+
```

And I'm expecting to get a JSON string like this:

```
[{"code":"brand","description":"microsoft"}, {"code":"color","description":"green"}, {"code":"size","description":"large"}]
```

So far my Google Apps Script code looks like this:

```
function tableJSON(arr) {
  var i, j, obj = {};
  for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
    obj[arr[0][j]] = {};
  }
  
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
      obj[arr[0][j]] = arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

And the result when I type

```
="[" & tableJSON(A1:B4) & "]"
```

is:

```
[{"code":"size","description":"large"}]
```

I'm sure the solution is simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

The code only creates 1 object and rewrites  the same object each time in iteration.

#### Solution:

- [Shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)  the 2D array to get headers
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to a object

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
/**
 * @param{Array<Array>} arr 2D array
 * @customfunction
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function tableJSONFixed(arr) {
  'use strict';
  const [code, desc] = arr.shift();
  return JSON.stringify(arr.map(([v1, v2]) => ({ [code]: v1, [desc]: v2 })));
}

console.info(
  tableJSONFixed([
    ['code', 'description'],
    ['brand', 'google'],
    ['size', 'large'],
    ['color', 'green'],
  ])
);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First time I see the new Stack Snippet console :)

Comment: @Rubén Wish they would integrate it directly. It's been 3 years, since it was updated in github.

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that you added it, nice :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop

I was using tabletop to convert sheets to JSON but if you have an organisational google account this isn't going to work for much longer